# Can I import chess games/moves into React Chessboard to just show the moves in a visual format? (Not actually playing)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, chess

I am developing an application where the user is shown many professional master-level chess games, and can watch the game being played on the board or analyze the game, but not actually play themselves.

I was wondering if the https://github.com/Clariity/react-chessboard/tree/main/example/src/boards React library would be enough to support this implementation? Or does it just allow users to play actual chess games?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[react-chessboard](https://github.com/Clariity/react-chessboard) (as far as I can see) doesn't have this functionality out-of-the-box, so this is not enough if you are looking for a complete working solution and are not planning to write much code yourself.

But if you want to write your own app and your source are e.g. PGN files, it is pretty easy to write a small GUI, and just pass the moves one by one, e.g. like `game.move('e4')`.